# Android : How Show My data on First Main Activity, my data Coming from third Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have 3 activities, Activity1, Activity2 and Activity3

In Activity1

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // activity Code is here 
}
```

I have a Button and **EditText** value. I send **EditText** value from  **Activity1** to **Activity2** using **Intent** .

I am getting Datavalue on **Activity2** with the help of **EditText** value coming from **Activity1** and send new datavalue **activity2** to **Activity3** after click on a button using **Intent**.

I am on **Activity3** page with some data value.

I want to send this data value **Activity3** to **Activity1** using **Intent** and want to display on **TextView**

In Activity C

```
Intent i = new Intent(Activity_C.this, Activity_A.class);   
String data = "SomeData";
i.putExtra("datavalue", strName);
startActivity(i);
```

In Activity A

```
EditText edittext= findViewById(R.id.edittext);
Bundle bundle=getIntent().getExtras();
String s=bundle.getString("datavalue");
edittext.setText(s);
```

I have no Idea Where i put this code in **Activity A**.When i put this code **OnCreate** Method in **Activity A** , Not working.. Because time of first execution this code giving error ...

How to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

In Activity C

```
Intent i = new Intent(Activity_C.this, Activity_A.class);   
String data = "SomeData";
i.putExtra("datavalue", strName);
startActivity(i);
```

In Activity A

```
EditText edittext= findViewById(R.id.edittext);
Bundle bundle=getIntent().getExtras();
String s=bundle.getString("datavalue");
edittext.setText(s);
```

This is how you have to pass the data and show it in the EditText

Comment: Thanks for reply........ where i should write this code in main activity  A. Create with new method or in oncreate method, OnCreate method already execute time of start activity..

Comment: paste the Activity A code in onCreate of Activity A

Answer (score -1):

The same how you used the intent from **Activity A -> Activity B** will also work for **Activity C -> Activity A**. What difficulty you are facing? can you show your code?

Comment: i am going on C to A but how i show my data on activity A. Code required.

Answer (score -1):

In Activity A Just write below code it will work:

```
EditText edittext = findViewById(R.id.edittext);
Bundle bundle=getIntent().getExtras();
String s=bundle.getString("datavalue");
if(s!=null)
{
    edittext.setText(s);
}
```